# Criar uma JPQL e definir a entidade em tempo de execução

Tags: java, jpa

Boa noite.

Gostaria de saber se há uma forma de fazer uma consulta JPQL e definir a entidade em tempo de execução, sem ter que concatenar ou interpolar String.

Exemplo utilizando interpolação:

```
public long getRecords(String entity){
    String q = String.format("COUNT(e) FROM %s e", entity);
    Query query = em.createQuery(q);
    return (long) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: Você pode dar um exemplo melhor? `String` não tem o método `getSingleResult()`. Além disso, gostaria de saber em que contexto este método é usado e de onde você obtém o parâmetro passado ao método, pois isso é importante para poder se elaborar uma resposta. Em especial gostaria de saber se você tem como saber qual é o objeto `Class<?>` da sua entidade.

Comment: Acrescentei o restante do código. Esse método será chamado durante uma requisição feita pelo usuário. Ele irá preencher os campos que serão gerados no banco. Não tenho como saber o Class<?> porque a entidade será gerada a partir de um arquivo .properties.

Comment: @helciodasilva tem classes envolvidas, ou seja, além desse count na tabela, existe a classe que retorna o conteudo de uma linha ou linhas de uma tabela?

Comment: Virgílio, não tem. Eu só preciso verificar se uma tabela está vazia.